# .htaccess: Rewrite URI GET-Parameters?

Tags: .htaccess, getparameter

I want my URL to look like this:

```
https://example-test.example.com/example-application_1.1/index.php?page=pagename&action=actionname
```

But the user should only type:

```
https://example-test.example.com/example-application_1.1/pagename/actionname/
```

Is it possible to make this run with a RewriteRule in .htaccess? I couldn't figure it out.

My .htaccess-file looks like this at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-test\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^example-application_1\.1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /example-application_1\.1/index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" index.php?page=$1&action=$2&$3 [L]
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/" index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

So if the user types in this:

```
https://example-prefix.example.com/pagename/actionname/id=123&category=456
```

The URL will be turned into this:

```
https://example-prefix.example.com/index.php?page=pagename&action=actionname&id=123&category=456
```

If you still want to have access on your files simply do this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)" index.php?page=$1&action=$2&$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/" index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example-application_1.1/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /example-application_1.1/?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

This should work.

In index.php, you can get variable: `$_GET['page']` & `$_GET['action']`.

Comment: Your htaccess is in /example-application_1.1/ ?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ ?page=$1&action=$2 [L]`

Comment: In your php, add before stylesheet import `<base href="/example-application_1.1/">`

Comment: `https://example-test.example.com/example-application_1.1/pagename/actionname/other/other/..` ?

Comment: If the user types in this: `https://example-test.example.com/pagename/actionname/?id=123&parent=456`It should redirect to this: `https://example-test.example.com/index.php?page=pagename&action=actionname&id=123&parent=456`For example.

Comment: It's not very practical, a php routing would be better

Comment: It is possible to speak directly? In the comments it's not easy.

Comment: stack-exchange?

Comment: I thought the site has a private courier

Comment: How do i use it?

Comment: I just discovered that there was not

Comment: I did it. Look at the answer I posted and probably give it a vote! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)" index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: This works, but now my php-file can't find the stylesheet or images?